# Repro seg fault when filtering zero row data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a reproducible seg fault with data.table when filtering on a zero row data.table.  I have tried this with both the CRAN and github versions.

```
library(data.table)
DT=as.data.table(list(V1=NULL))
DT[V1==0] # seg fault.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nice catch, please test with latest data.table version and the report it [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues). StackOverflow isn't meant for bug reports.

Comment: ok, i've raised an issue on github.